# Where is a mistake in HAProxy configuration?

Tags: centos, openvpn, haproxy

I have a problem with HAProxy configuration. I have several backend servers and in most cases, redirections are being done correctly. It works everywhere except one backend, where Rocket.Chat is configured.
HAProxy is redirecting traffic for two domains and subdomains to correct Virtual Machines which are installed on my two bare-metal Hyper-V Servers. Everything is connected via OpenVPN with split-tunnelling. All domains are subdomains are correctly set up in Cloudflare DNS.
The problem is that one redirection is not working properly. I have many backends, but only one, with Rocket.Chat is being forwarded to incorrect backend.

**Frontend and backend configuration:**

```
    bind *:5000
    acl url_static       path_beg       -i /static /images /javascript /stylesheets
    acl url_static       path_end       -i .jpg .gif .png .css .js

    use_backend static          if url_static
    default_backend             app


#Frontend for traffic to VPN. 
frontend https--in
        bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /etc/cert/
        mode http
        option httplog
        use_backend cloud if { hdr_dom(host) -i cloud.domain.dev }     { dst_port 443 }
        use_backend cloud if { hdr_dom(host) -i www.cloud.domain.dev }     { dst_port 443 }
        use_backend steldev if { hdr_dom(host) -i www.domain.dev }     { dst_port 443 }
        use_backend steldev if { hdr_dom(host) -i domain.dev }     { dst_port 443 }
        use_backend chat if { hdr_dom(host) -i chatx.domain.dev }     { dst_port 443 }
        use_backend adsb if { hdr_dom(host) -i adsb.domain2.xyz }     { dst_port 443 }
        use_backend monitoring if { hdr_dom(host) -i monitoring.domain.dev }     { dst_port 443 }
        use_backend itsm if { hdr_dom(host) -i itsm.domain.dev }     { dst_port 443 }
        use_backend itsm if { hdr_dom(host) -i itsm.domain2.xyz }     { dst_port 443 }
        use_backend board if { hdr_dom(host) -i board.domain2.xyz }     { dst_port 443 }

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# static backend for serving up images, stylesheets and such
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend static
    balance     roundrobin
    server      static 127.0.0.1:4331 check

---------------------------------------------------------------------
# round robin balancing between the various backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend app
    balance     roundrobin
    server  app1 127.0.0.1:5001 check
    server  app2 127.0.0.1:5002 check
    server  app3 127.0.0.1:5003 check
    server  app4 127.0.0.1:5004 check

backend cloud
        balance leastconn
        option httpclose
        cookie JSESSIONID prefix
        server node1 10.11.12.2:80 cookie A check

backend monitoring
        balance leastconn
        option httpclose
        cookie JSESSIONID prefix
        server node1 10.11.12.7:80 cookie A check

backend steldev
        balance leastconn
        option httpclose
        cookie JSESSIONID prefix
        server node1 10.11.12.4:80 cookie A check

backend chat                    #That one is forwarding to steldev on 10.11.12.4:80, not chat.
        balance roundrobin
        server node1 10.11.12.5:3000 cookie A   check

backend itsm
        balance leastconn
        option httpclose
        cookie JSESSIONID prefix
        server node1 10.11.12.9:80      cookie A check

backend board
        balance leastconn
        option httpclose
        cookie JSESSIONID prefix
        server node1 10.11.12.10:80      cookie A check


backend adsb
        balance leastconn
        option httpclose
        cookie JSESSIONID prefix
        server node1 10.11.12.3:88 cookie A check
```

I completely do not know what is wrong with chatx.domain.dev (**chat** backend) configuration.

If this is important: CentOS 8.3, kernel 4.18, HAProxy v1.8.23

Does anyone of you see any mistake in my configuration? I'm pretty new in HAProxy.

Answer (score 0):

Line

```
use_backend steldev if { hdr_dom(host) -i domain.dev }     { dst_port 443 }
```

means
*.domain.dev

So the line

```
use_backend chat if { hdr_dom(host) -i chatx.domain.dev }     { dst_port 443 }
```

doesn`t work, cause works previous line.

Put line with '**-i domain.dev**' at last position.